# Suspend debugger when a variable value changes

Tags: python, debugging, python-3.x, pycharm

A variable `X` changes its value at some **unknown** point in my program.

Using conditional breakpoints I can make the execution stop when my variable `X` gets a different value:

[image]

but this would require that I place the same breakpoint in every single line of a program with 15k lines, which is impractical.

---

**Question:**
Is there a way to make the debugger stop if a variable value is changed anywhere in the code?